# robovm blackscreen after resume on IOS

Tags: java, ios, libgdx, robovm

I have a libgdx app. It used to work fine on both Android and IOS while I was using libgdx 1.1.4 and robovm 1.0.0.Beta version. Recently I upgraded to libgdx 1.6.3 and robovm 1.4. Now Android version works fine but there is a little glitch with IOS application. The problem is,if I pause the app by pressing the home button and then resume it, I get a black screen. App does not crash. I don't see anything in the logs either.

Does anyone have any ideas what could be going on ?

I'd really appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

**__UPDATE__**

What stroke me is the fact that, when I resume the game, none of the resume methods (neither the one in XXXGame class nor in the XXXScreen class) gets called. Just to be precise, I have log statements in all those methods to see how program flow goes. I see logs when I paused the game but nothing when I resume it.

This looks to me a fundamental problem because, as you know, resume method is part of libgdx life cycle methods and should be called no matter what. Problem can not be at libgdx side because app works fine on Android. So, I am wondering if something is wrong on robovm side. Am I missing something there?

**__UPDATE2__**

I created a new libgdx project using gui to find out if the same problem occurs on IOS platform. It looks like pause-resume-pause-resume works fine on a new project. So I started comparing new project against mine. My game class inherits from com.badlogic.gdx.Game but the new project's game class implements com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter. I have changed it to make them match. It didn't break the new project.

The default implementation was lacking resume method on Game class. So I added the following:

```
    @Override
    public void resume() {
//      super.resume();
        Gdx.app.log("Testing", "resume");
    }
```

To my surprise, in the logs, I see two sets of resume messages as follows:

```
2015-07-01 08:05:52.435 IOSLauncher[54152:2661071] [debug] IOSApplication: created
2015-07-01 08:05:52.706 IOSLauncher[54152:2661071] [debug] IOSApplication: resumed
2015-07-01 08:05:59.093 IOSLauncher[54152:2661071] [debug] IOSApplication: paused
2015-07-01 08:05:59.093 IOSLauncher[54152:2661071] [info] Testing: pause
2015-07-01 08:06:00.670 IOSLauncher[54152:2661071] [debug] IOSApplication: resumed
2015-07-01 08:06:00.670 IOSLauncher[54152:2661071] [info] Testing: resume
2015-07-01 08:06:04.587 IOSLauncher[54152:2661071] [debug] IOSApplication: paused
2015-07-01 08:06:04.587 IOSLauncher[54152:2661071] [info] Testing: pause
2015-07-01 08:06:06.640 IOSLauncher[54152:2661071] [debug] IOSApplication: resumed
2015-07-01 08:06:06.640 IOSLauncher[54152:2661071] [info] Testing: resume
2015-07-01 08:06:09.300 IOSLauncher[54152:2661071] [debug] IOSApplication: paused
2015-07-01 08:06:09.300 IOSLauncher[54152:2661071] [info] Testing: pause
```

I was not sure where this **IOSLauncher[54152:2661071] [debug] IOSApplication: resumed** line was logged. I commented out **super.resume()** in the method to prevent it but it didn't help.

I checked my own app to see if I was getting something similar to **IOSLauncher[54152:2661071] [debug] IOSApplication: resumed** but I couldn't.

While I was fiddling with the code and documenting what I was doing here, I found the problem. I will post it here soon.

Comment: Are you using FrameBuffers and generating them in the resize or create methods?

Comment: @Tenfour04 Thank you for your time. But, no, I am not using FrameBuffers.

Comment: easy way to find if the problem is libgdx or robovm is to build with libgdx 1.6.3 and robovm 1.0.0.Beta. If the problem is gone its Robovm, otherwise it's libgdx.

Comment: @p.streef Thank you for your comment. Robovm's 1.0.0 version does not support IOS 8+. (and my earlier builds works on IOS7.). But your comment was still useful. I tried nightlies for both libgdx and robovm but still no progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. I am going to document it here with the hope that It may save time to someone else.

Below methods are from IOSLauncher.java (in IOS project)

```
  @Override
  public void didBecomeActive (UIApplication application) {
      FacebookManager.getInstance().handleDidBecomeActive(application);
  }


  @Override
  public void willTerminate (UIApplication application) {
      FacebookManager.getInstance().handleWillTerminate(application);
  }
```

Above code used to work fine without any glitch on earlier version of libgdx/robovm. Actually I had done whatever mentioned in [robovm IOS bindings](https://github.com/BlueRiverInteractive/robovm-ios-bindings) back then. However it is a no-go-go now. Below changes to these methods fix the problem:

```
  @Override
  public void didBecomeActive (UIApplication application) {
      super.didBecomeActive(application);
      FacebookManager.getInstance().handleDidBecomeActive(application);
  }


  @Override
  public void willTerminate (UIApplication application) {
      super.willTerminate(application);
      FacebookManager.getInstance().handleWillTerminate(application);
  }
```

I thank everyone who took their time and shared their valuable comments with on this issue.